# Das Thema ist bei mir durch!

Tags: meaning

I came across the expression:

> Das Thema ist bei mir durch!

What does it mean? And when to use it?

Comment: Some context would be very useful, please.

Comment: @Beta: "When to use it?" besagt, dass der User einen passenden Kontext sucht.

Comment: "Exactly" ist fast immer eine schlechte Eingrenzung der Antworten, da Bedeutungen oft nicht exact sind. Die Herkunft eines Wortes kann zwar oft sicher belegt werden, aber Bedeutungen wandeln sich oft.

Comment: It means the same as "der Drops ist für mich gelutscht"

Answer (score 6):

Benutzt werden kann der Ausdruck, wenn Du eine weitere Diskussion zum Thema ablehnst, sei es kraft Deiner Autorität, oder als private Entscheidung. Vielleicht steht Deine Meinung endgültig fest oder Du bist die Diskussion darüber schlicht leid.

Entweder Du hast Dich ausreichend mit dem Thema beschäftigt um Deine Entscheidung unverrückbar zu machen, weitere Appelle sind sinnlos:

> Ich erlaube Dir nicht im Sommer nach Jordanien zu reisen - das Thema
>   ist bei mir durch!

Der Satz würde nicht passen, wenn noch nie über Jordanienurlaub diskutiert worden wäre. Je häufiger, desto eher.

> Diskussionsforum zu Flüchtlingen? Bitte nicht - das Thema ist bei mir durch.

Man kann das auch sagen, ohne eine feste Meinung, geschweige eine autoritative, gefällt zu haben. Man möchte sich vielleicht einfach vom Thema fernhalten.

An einer Bushaltestelle kann man auch fragen, ob die Linie 8 schon durch ist. Sie war da, ist aber wieder weg. "Ja, der 8er ist hier vor 4 Minuten durch."

Ein Stück Fleisch ist gut durch, wenn es lange genug gegart hat.

Answer (score 3):

This phrase means that some issue is no longer of interest.

In your example it means that the speaker is no longer interested in the matter and not willing to discuss it any further.

Another example:

> «Das Thema ist durch», sagte der neue Landesinnenminister Herbert Reul (CDU) der «Westdeutschen Zeitung» (Samstag). «Ich sehe da keine Handlungsnotwendigkeit.» [1](https://www.welt.de/regionales/nrw/article166679272/Das-Thema-ist-durch.html)

meaning that there won't be any further activities in the matter (here: The "Blitzmarathon", a large-scale speed limit enforcement campaign)